# How make auto scroll down when new element is added?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I'm making messenger style chat.

My HTML

```
<div class="mechanism">
    <input type="text" class="textbox"></input>
    <button class="send">send</button>
</div>
```

Nothing much. I haven't started CSS yet (well I did little bit to align stuff)

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var textbox = document.querySelector('.textbox');
var sendBtn = document.querySelector('.send');

var paragraph = '';

textbox.addEventListener (
    'input', function () {
        paragraph = this.value;
    }
);
sendBtn.addEventListener (
    'click', function () {
        var newP = document.createElement('h2');
        document.body.appendChild(newP);
        newP.textContent = paragraph;
        textbox.value = '';
        textbox.focus();
        paragraph = '';
    }
);
textbox.addEventListener(
    "keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        sendBtn.click();
    }
  }
);
```

And when I type some messages it doesn't scroll down. I googled it even checked on this site but couldn't find answer, some of them didn't work.

I tried this too

```
.scrollIntoView();
```

but that didn't work.

And if there's a way without jQuery, that would be nice :)

And also input has position fixed

Comment: But you want the input to also stay in view, even when scrolling down? Then why not insert the new content *above* the inputbox, instead of *below* it? Is that acceptable?

Comment: @trincot input has position: fixed; i guess i need to add css too :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the new element :

```
var element = document.getElementById(newElement);
```

and the first for instant scroll and second for smooth scroll:

```
element.scrollIntoView();

element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```

Here is a useful webpage
: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: hmm ... ok. maybe u can copy and paste what u tried?

Comment: maybe you should check for a typo

Comment: If this helped you, you can click on the checkmark to confirm it as an solution.